# Can I trust a pipeline 'succeeded' status with OutOfMemoryError in the job log?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow job with Autoscaling enabled, which resized the worker pool to 14 during execution. By the time the job had finished the job log reported 6 `OutOfMemoryError`s but the whole pipeline, as well as each execution step, had status `succeeded`. Can I trust the job status, or could I have data loss due to the worker failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trust the job status and results, because Dataflow is designed to process data in a way that is resilient to such failures.  Further information can be found in the description of [Service Optimization and Execution](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc).  Specifically:

> The Dataflow service is fault-tolerant, and may retry your code
>   multiple times in the case of worker issues. The Dataflow service may
>   create backup copies of your code, and can have issues with manual
>   side effects (such as if your code relies upon or creates temporary
>   files with non-unique names).